# Buttons don't respond on several mobiles(galaxy S3,S4 and higher)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a weird question:
Why the hell the links on my homepage does not respond on galaxy S3 and S4?
It is important to mention that the other pages respond well!

here is the link:
http://www.hommyfood.co.il

Please help! Almost a week on this topic.

Comment: It's entirely unclear what exactly you're asking. Please specify which buttons do not work, and try to recreate this in a **smaller** sample.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not clicking on a random link from an unknown website. Could you provide more details, or replicate the problem on a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @freefaller I wish to state here for the record that if you're afraid to click on links, maybe this is not the right site for you. And links to jsfiddle are just as risky as "unknown" links; here is an example: [http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6XhLe/](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/6XhLe/)

Comment: I'll try to recreate this problem in  a smaller version.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing the banner on the mobile version.